# Is it possible to open ios application view after VoIP call has ended and the application was in terminated state?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, callkit, pushkit

I have implemented the starting of VoIP call from terminated state using CallKit and push notifications. The starting and ending of the call works fine.

Is it possible to open the application's view after the call has ended? Currently if the application is terminated then after the call the app remains terminated.

Comment: Do you want to launch the application?

Comment: yes, I do wish to launch it

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to auto launch app. launch of app depend on user action.